# getting a selection box to set a default value using the latest value in a mysql database

Tags: php, html, mysql, drop-down-menu, selected

Need some help on this PHP and MySQL query.
The selection box gets populated properly but for selecting the current set default value I cant seem to get the if statement it to work. been trying to find an answer everywhere to this question but cant seem to get it.

What I'm trying to do is to just select the latest row from the table TOP and to see if the field BRAND equals the SN field from the table BRANDS

hope someone can shed some light on my failings here cause I'm doing my head in.

```html
<select name="top">
<?php
$query = $db->query("SELECT * FROM BRANDS");
$querytop = $db->query("SELECT MAX(NUM) FROM TOP");
$rtop = $querytop->fetch_object();
while($row = $query->fetch_object()){
if ($row->SN == $rtop->BRAND){
echo "<option value='".$row->SN."' selected=\"selected\">".$row->BRAND."</option>";
}else{
echo "<option value='".$row->SN."'>".$row->BRAND."</option>";
}
}
?>
</select>
```

EDIT1:

Here's the HTML I'm getting; the **$rtop->BRAND** does not return a value. therefore the if statement is always false, even if it; logically speaking, should return true.

```html
<select name="top">
 <option value='21'>asd</option>
    <option value='22'>Test1</option> 
</select>
```

Comment: could you post the html-result of your list? Did you checked if this part of your code $row->SN == $rtop->BRAND ist ever true?

Comment: Thank you for posting the html. It seems you never get into your if-part of this code: if ($row->SN == $rtop->BRAND){
echo "<option value='".$row->SN."' selected=\"selected\">".$row->BRAND."</option>";
}else{
echo "<option value='".$row->SN."'>".$row->BRAND."</option>";
}. Try to check, why this happens.

Comment: I have seen you already checked that. See my answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the problem I faced was that I was only selecting the NUM field when im actually trying to find the BRAND value from the num field.
the correction

```html
$querytop = $db->query("SELECT BRAND FROM toppage WHERE NUM=(SELECT max(NUM) FROM toppage)");
```

the code in full

```html
<?php
 $query = $db->query("SELECT * FROM BRANDS");
 $querytop = $db->query("SELECT BRAND FROM toppage WHERE NUM=(SELECT max(NUM) FROM toppage)");
 $rtop = $querytop->fetch_object();
 while($row = $query->fetch_object()){
     if ($row->SN == $rtop->BRAND){
       echo "<option value='$row->SN' selected=\"selected\">".$row->BRAND."</option>";
     }else{
       echo "<option value='$row->SN'>".$row->BRAND."</option>";
     }
    }
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```html
Please Try This type..:)
if ($row->SN == $rtop->BRAND){
echo "<option value='{$row->SN}' selected=\"selected\">"{$row->BRAND}"</option>";
}else{
echo "<option value='{$row->SN}'>"{$row->BRAND}"</option>";
}
```

Comment: no sorry that dosnt work. I think it is more the fetching of the data in this case

Comment: yeah Sorry...Please try this finally once... echo "<option value='{$row->SN}' selected=\"selected\">"{$row->BRAND}"</option>";

Answer (score 0):

I think, this shoud help you:

```
$querytop = $db->query("SELECT MAX(NUM) FROM TOP");
```

change to:

```
$querytop = $db->query("SELECT MAX(NUM) AS BRAND FROM TOP");
```

Comment: thanks for the help, this gave me a bit of a brainwave. my solution though came out very differently. Your answer would output the BRAND as the id NUM instead of find the ID (NUM) then output the BRAND. See my answer if interested.